# REST Authorization

Tags: rest

We have Rest calls like http://api.ourdomain.com/dashboard/resource-id  Method: GET; where resource-id is the id of a resource which is tied to a logged-in user. We don't want any user be able to access other user's resources.

Thus, to determine if the resource is tied to the current logged-in user, we have to execute some queries(Joins) to know that this resource with resource-id is of logged-in user. Well, this is one of many cases we have. We certainly can't make a generalized AOP kind of method which will decide if requested resource is authorized to see by logged-in user, because the logic to decide that, is different for different resources. Other solution could be: to have "createdBy" column in every "resource" DB table so that the logic for deciding would be pretty simple i.e. just check if current logged-in user == resource record's createdBy column. But the latter seems a bit quirky one. Any suggestion, how we can design solution for this?

Comment: How do you know the logged-in user?

Comment: We get the userId in the cookie and we get the User object from the DB using userId and check if the user object has logged-in == true.

Comment: "because the logic to decide that, is different for different resources" Sounds like you need logic in each resource to determine if a user can see it. This seems more of a business logic question than a REST/Http issue. At the moment how are user permissions or roles worked out?

Comment: Agreed. The internal implementation details have nothing to do with REST. Also, using a cookie for that isn't RESTful, since it's an unnecessary coupling to HTTP. You should be using the Authorization header on every request.

Comment: I didn't find this one before, but there is same question raised already which is unanswered.I am looking for authorization past authentication, resource level authorization to be specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634764/resource-level-authorization-in-restful-service

Comment: I am also looking for same "authorization past authentication, resource level authorization to be specific." How to avoid database call or long logic to authorize resources?